# How do I typeset a fraction of Young tableaux?

Tags: fractions, ytableau

How do I typeset a fraction of Young tableaux so that the fraction is nicely spaced and diagonal?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{youngtab} % for Young tableaux
\usepackage{young} % for Young tableaux
\begin{document}
This looks horrible
\[\frac{\young(345,23,1) }{ \young(531,31,1)}\]
So does this
\[\sfrac{\young(345,23,1) }{ \young(531,31,1)}\]
This isn't bad, but the separator is small, and the spacing is not so good.
\[\nicefrac{\young(345,23,1) }{ \young(531,31,1)}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You ought to try my package `ytableau`, which is strictly better than both of those put together.  This does not address your fractions question, however.

Comment: in all the answers so far, the fraction slash is visually off center.  since the adjacent sides of the tableau aren't symmetrical, i'd try just to get the spacing between the top rows to look "right".  to approximate that, i think that getting the point of the slash that cuts the vertical midpoint of the top row to be centered horizontally between the edges would look better than any of the attempts so far.  maybe this can be calculated using `tikz` (i'm not good enough with that package to attempt it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the good old `\middle` since then the `/` is automatically scaled and a proper glyph is used. The only problem is that the tableaux are not vertically centered; a trick with `array` solved this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{youngtab} % for Young tableaux
\usepackage{young} % for Young tableaux

\newcommand\mathcenter[1]{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand\yngfrac[2]{\left.\mathcenter{#1}\,\middle/\,\mathcenter{#2}\right.}

\begin{document}
\[\yngfrac{ \young(345,23,1) }{ \young(531,31,1) }\]
\[\yngfrac{ \young(345,23) }{ \young(531,1) }\]
\[\yngfrac{ \young(345,23) }{ \young(531,31,1) }\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico That's quite true. I wanted it to be short and similar to stuff like `\sfrac`. Nevertheless, `\yngfrac` should do the job ;)

Comment: A separate thought: Instead of using an `array` to center the two tableaux, you could make use of the TeX primitives `\vcenter` and `\hbox` to define `\mathcenter` as `\newcommand\mathcenter[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach could be the package `graphicx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,youngtab} 
\begin{document}
\young(345,23,1)\raisebox{.6em}{\resizebox{1.5em}{3em}{/ }}\young(531,31,1)
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

If you are worried with the slope or thickness of the resized `/`, another approach could be draw a sloped line in a picture environment, where you have control of the line  position:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1em}
\begin{document}
\young(345,23,1)
\begin{picture}(1,3)(0.5,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,3){1.11}}
\end{picture}
\young(531,31,1)
\end{document}
```

Or a rotated rule for tuning the thickness:

[image: MWE3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,youngtab} 
\setlength{\unitlength}{1em}

\begin{document}

\young(345,23,1)
\begin{picture}(0.5,0)(.6,0)
\put(-0.5,0){\rotatebox{-25}{\rule{.04em}{3.7em}}}
\end{picture}
\young(531,31,1)

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem of this sort of solutions is that the stroke comes out too thick :-/

Comment: @tohecz May be in this MWE... but you can change the content of the box, for instance, by `~~/~~~`. Thin enough?

Comment: I don't see how it helps, you can as well change `1.5em` to something smaller with a very similar effect, but then you get a very vertical slash ;)

Comment: @tohecz Too thick, too upright ... you're too picky `;)`. BTW +1 for your answer.

Comment: I just try to get the best possible for reasonable (time) costs :)

Comment: I like the simplicity of this one. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{youngtab} % for Young tableaux
\usepackage{young} % for Young tableaux


\newcommand{\YoungFrac}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        outer sep=2pt,
        baseline={(current bounding box.center)}
        ]
    \node (A) {\young(#1)} ;
    \node[anchor=west,xshift=10pt]
        at (A.east) (B)
        {\young(#2)} ;
    \draw (A.south east) -- (B.north west) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    }


\begin{document}
\YoungFrac{345,23,1}{531,31,1}
\end{document}
```